# Make a composite key "bidirectional"

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, composite-key

I have a table where I use a composite key as primary key. Its created something like:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO(
    BAR1 INT,
    BAR2 INT,
PRIMARY KEY (BAR1, BAR2))
```

BAR1 and BAR2 are FK:s for other tables and I would like to make sure there is always zero or one tuples in my FOO table where both those keys exist at the same time. Basicaly I would like it at the same time to be like:

```
PRIMARY KEY (BAR2, BAR1)
```

At the same time the keys must both be allowed to be paired an arbitrary number of times with other keys so they cannot each of them be unique.

So when I have done

```
INSERT INTO FOO VALUES (1,2);
```

the schema would disallow

```
INSERT INTO FOO VALUES (2,1);
```

What is a good way to solve this in mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to use a trigger.

```
create trigger bi_foo before insert on foo
for each row
begin
  if exists(select 1 from foo where bar1 = NEW.bar2 and bar2 = NEW.bar1)
  then
    signal sqlstate '50000' set message_text="Oops";
  end if;
end
```

This will work:

```
insert into foo values (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6);
insert into foo values (3, 2), (3, 5), (1, 6);
```

This will fail:

```
mysql> insert into foo values (2, 1);
ERROR 1644 (50000): Oops
```

Comment: Also requires an UPDATE trigger making a similar check.

Comment: @sqlvogel, It is unclear from the OP if the application updates this table or not, given that bar1+bar2 is considered a primary key, but I agree with you here: an update trigger will be needed as well if update happens.

Comment: This seems reasonable at a theoretical level. I get a syntax error when I try to create the suggested trigger. @sqlvogel : To make it clear, yes the appplication updates this table.

Comment: @einar, don't forget to set a delimiter when creating triggers, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: This solved the problem for Mysql in general but not for the particular installation I'm forced to use. When running 
delimiter //
create trigger bi_foo before insert on FOO
for each row
begin
  if exists(select 1 from FOO where BAR1 = NEW.BAR2 and BAR2 = NEW.bar1)
  then
    signal sqlstate '50000' set message_text="Oops";
  end if;
end
at InnoDB on my localhost I get proper results. But using the MyIsam I have to use I get ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 87
STR: // This is likely to be some limitations at the service provider.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I've understood your requirement but I think you will want one of the following.

1. Ensure that only one possible pairing of BAR1/BAR2 values can exist in FOO:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE FOO(
       BAR1 INT,
       BAR2 INT,
   CHECK (BAR1<=BAR2),
   PRIMARY KEY (BAR1, BAR2));
   ```
2. Ensure that both pairings must always exist:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE FOO(
       BAR1 INT,
       BAR2 INT,
   FOREIGN KEY (BAR2, BAR1) REFERENCES FOO (BAR1, BAR2),
   PRIMARY KEY (BAR1, BAR2));
   ```

Comment: In MySQL "The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

Comment: You are right. I tried it and INSERT INTO FOO VALUES(2,1); followed by INSERT INTO FOO VALUES(1,2); was allowed. That was what I wanted to prevent.

Comment: I didn't notice the MySQL tag. Integrity constraints are an essential feature of any DBMS. That MySQL can't enforce simple constraints is arguably one very good reason not to use MySQL for this.

Comment: I don't think (2) would work without deferred constraints (also not supported by MySQL) to break the chicken-and-egg problem.